# Turn off the node to an Aurora Cluster on AWS using GitHub Actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, github-actions, amazon-aurora

I am trying to turn off this node that we have on our aurora database, using GitHub Actions pipeline, but instead of turning off the node, I am able to turn off the whole cluster which I don't want, is there a way that I can only turn off the single node ?
This is the pipeline that I am using to turn off the cluster:

```
  - name: Turn Off the Database
    run: |
       aws rds stop-db-cluster --db-cluster-identifier evoya-alpha-aurora-cluster
```

This is the picture for reference:
[image]

I just want to turn off the 'alpha-aurora-node-' not the whole cluster.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Aurora does not support stopping individual instances/nodes. `stop-db-cluster` is the only option. It looks like you only have a one node cluster anyway, so what would be the difference?